# showing this mark ? in my url when i submit login form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, material-ui

I am new to react and I use material UI for login when I click the login button my URL change and my input data will empty.

Before click on the Login button URL: http://localhost:3000/#/login
After click on the Login button URL: http://localhost:3000/?#/login

Why did this is happening

```
const handleLogin = () => {

  let payload = {
    "username": `${username}`,
    "password": `${password}`
  };
  const config = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE',
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization'
    }
  }
  axios.post(LOGIN, payload, config )
  .then(response => {
    cookies.set('access_token', response.data.token);
    window.localStorage.setItem('access_token', response.data.token)

    if (response.status === 200) {
      history.push({
        pathname: '/dashboard',
        customNameData:  response.data.user[0].userType,
      })
      window.sessionStorage.setItem("userType", response.data.user[0].userType);
      window.sessionStorage.setItem("Name", response.data.user[0].name);
      window.sessionStorage.setItem("ID", response.data.user[0]._id);
      window.location.reload();
    }
  }).catch(err => {
    console.warn("Error while Login.....");
  });
}
```

And This is my Login Return code

```
  return (
<div className='login-background'>
<Container>
  <Row>
    <Col md={4} className='login-form'>
      <h3 className='center-content' style={{fontWeight:600}}>LOGIN</h3>
      <form className={classes.root} noValidate autoComplete="off">
        <div>
          <TextField
            required
            id="outlined-required"
            label="Username"
            variant="outlined"
            className='input-field'
            onChange={(e)=> setUsername(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <TextField
            id="outlined-password-input"
            label="Password"
            type="password"
            autoComplete="current-password"
            variant="outlined"
            className='input-field'
            onChange={(e)=> setPassword(e.target.value)}
            required
          />
        </div>
        <Row  style={{padding:10}} >
          <Col md={6}>
          <Row>
            <Checkbox
              className={classes.root}
              disableRipple
              color="default"
              checkedIcon={<span className={clsx(classes.icon, classes.checkedIcon)} />}
              icon={<span className={classes.icon} />}
              inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'decorative checkbox' }}
              {...props}
            />
            <p className='remember-text'>Remember Me</p>
            </Row>
          </Col>
          <Col md={6}>
            <p className='remember-text' style={{textAlign:'right'}}>Forgot Password?</p>
          </Col>
        </Row>
            <Button type='submit' onClick={handleLogin} className='login-btn'>
              Login
            </Button>
          <p className='center-content ac-text'>Don't have an account? <b>Sign Up</b></p>
        </form>
      </Col>
      <Col md={8}>
      </Col>
    </Row>
  </Container>
</div>);
```

Comment: Please share us and the form code

Comment: Yes i will add my login code

Comment: `Access-Control-*` headers are **response** headers, not request headers. They **do not** belong in your client-side code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Submitting a form, unless you have set its method to `post` will **navigate to a new URL** consisting of:

- The `action` (defaulting to the URL of the current page with everything after the path removed)
- The start of query string marker: `?`
- The successful controls (e.g. non-disabled inputs with names and values) in the format `name=value` separated with `&` characters.

(I glossed over some nuances there).

---

If you plan to handle the form submission with Ajax then you need to prevent the default behaviour that the browser will do.

```
const Component = () => {
    const submitHandler = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        // Insert your logic here
    }

    return <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>...</form>
}
```

---

Re edit: Best practise for handling form submissions with JS is to use the submit event of the form and *not* the click event of the submit button.

Answer (score 0):

You should read more about the javascript and events.
in this case you have to prevent the form action.
like this:

```
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
   event.preventDefault();
  // call the api
}

<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>

  <button>click me</button>
</form>
```

ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Comment: Sure, I will read this URL. Thanks, Buddy.